# Strongloop Callback to allow a Datasource to notify of a change in data?

Tags: callback, datasource, strongloop

In Strongloop loop back is there a way for a Datasource to initiate processing (for example if the value of a piece of data changes) by registering a callback with a Datasource?

Answer (score 1):

you can use model hooks to implement what you want, but there is no way out of box.

1. create a model hook for the beforeSave event
2. do a diff with existing data in the datasource
3. save it if it changed, reject it otherwise

see http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Model+hooks for more info